# Wait for process to end OR user input to continue

Tags: bash, macos, kill

I have a bash script that runs a command in the background. After it executes it, it displays to the user: `Press any key to continue` (powered by `read -n1 -r -p 'Press any key to continue' value`)

I would like to have something monitor the command in the background to see when it is finished, and if it is, I want the script to continue anyway. On the other hand, the process could still be going, and I would like to enable the user to press a key to `kill` that process instead of waiting for it to complete.

---

I guess the easiest way to visualize it would be like this:

[image: mac shut down]

The user can either wait for the timer to go to 0 and it will shut down automatically, or if they click the shut down button it immediately shuts down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wait on the pid until the user hits a key, you can do it as follows:

```
./long_command.sh &
waitpid=$!
echo "Hit any key to continue or wait until the command finishes"
while kill -0 ${waitpid} > /dev/null ; do
    #if [[ ${#KEY} -gt 0 ]] ; then
    if read -n 1 -t 1 KEY ; then
        kill ${waitpid}
        break
    fi
done
```

Just replace `long_command.sh` by your command. Here `$!` returns the pid of the last started subprocess and `kill -0 ${waitpid}` checks if the process is still existing (it's not killing the process). `ps -q ${waitpid}` works on Linux as well, but not on Mac - thank you @leetbacoon for mentioning this. `read -n 1 -t 1` means "read one character, but only wait up to 1 second" (you could also use fractions like 0.5 here). The return status of this command depends on, if it could read a character in the specified time, or not.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, however I had to use `kill -0 "${waitpid}"` instead of `ps -q ${waitpid}` because macOS's version of `ps` doesn't have that flag.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. `kill -0` isn't even documented in the linux man page,. I guess it means signal 0, but signal zero is not listed if I issue `kill -l` but it works there as well. good you found it! I update it in the answer because it seems more portable.

Comment: Can't remember where I saw it but `kill -0` doesn't kill anything, it just checks if that process is running. If it is, exit code is `0`. If it isn't, exit code is ≥ `1` (afaik it's only 1 but to be on the safe side I'd say ≥ 1).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you

```
#!/bin/bash

doStuff() {
    local pidOfParent="$1"

    for i in $(seq 10); do
        echo "stuff ${i}" > /dev/null
        sleep 1
    done

    kill $pidOfParent
}

doStuff $$ &

doStuffPid="$!"

read -n1 -rp 'Press any key to continue' && kill $doStuffPid
```

**Break down**

`doStuff` is our function that contains what you want to be running in the background i.e. the music.

`$$` is the PID of the running script, which we pass into our function to become the more descriptive `pidOfParent` in which we `kill` after we've finished doing stuff.

The `&` after calling the function puts it in the background.

`$!` gets the PID of the last executed command, thus we now have the PID of the background process we just started.

You provided `read -n1 -rp 'Press any key to continue'` so I can assume you already know what that does, `&& kill $doStuffPid` will `kill` the background process when `read` has exited (this also works if you terminate the script using `^C`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use embedded expect, you can write:

```
expect <(cat <<'EOD'
spawn sleep 10
send_user "Press any key to continue\n"
stty raw -echo
expect {
  -i $user_spawn_id -re ".+" {}
  -i $spawn_id eof {}
}
EOD
)
```

where you would replace `sleep 10` with your process.